# Best way to hide a popup menu?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a control that creates a popup menu on right click, and I need the best way to close it on left click. Besides handling the mouseDown event of everycontrol in my application, what is the best way to close the popup menu?

Like a global mouse click event....

```
    private void lbKeywords_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
                listBoxMenu.ShowPopup(Cursor.Position);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This popup is it a `ContexMenuStrip`?

Comment: Shouldn't it close automatically once you click anywhere else in the screen!!?

Comment: Is this a custom form you are showing on right click?  You need to provide a little code or better description of what "popup menu" means.

Comment: Yes it is a custom object from devExpress. I have added the show code to the top.

Comment: Try asking DevExpress or looking at their support pages - i.e. I found this after a quick search: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/CQ14210.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. Put that as answer and I will mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an answer: try asking DevExpress or looking at their support pages - i.e. I found this after a quick search: [devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/CQ14210.aspx](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/CQ14210.aspx)